# How to send messages on a transaction in the Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I want to send a message on a transaction. Here is my codes:

```
_data = web3.toHex('xxxx');

instance.function_name(param1, param2, param3, param4, {value: web3.toWei(_price, 'ether'), from: web3.eth.accounts[0], data:_data}).then(...);
```

The transaction is processed successfully, But the input data message is not the `_data` value in the [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io)

can anybody help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` field in the transaction object is used when deploying a contract or when using the general `sendTransaction` or `sendRawTransaction` methods. If you are using a contract instance, the `data` field is ignored.

From the [Solidity docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods):

> Object - (optional) The (previous) last parameter can be a transaction object, see web3.eth.sendTransaction parameter 1 for more. **Note: data and to properties will not be taken into account.**

If you want to send the data manually, use [`sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction).

The information shown in Etherscan is the decoded data from the signed transaction describing the function call made. It is not free form user data (if that's what you're trying to insert). The first 32 bits of the data are the function signature and each 256 bit block afterwards are the parameters.

See [this source](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f) for more in-depth information.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I want to know how does crypto kitties do like this [store message](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6a2987596ad33f804bcd8bb33a1c12ff1ee2b2f30f016618694ef12e1d343e05)